# Loop through XML in Python

Tags: python, xml, pandas, loops, elementtree

My data set is as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<depts xmlns="http://SOMELINK" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        date="2021-01-15">
 <dept dept_id="00001" 
            col_two="00001value" 
            col_three="00001false"
            name = "some_name">     
    <owners>
      <currentowner col_four="00001value" 
                    col_five="00001value" 
                    col_six="00001false"
                    name = "some_name">
        <addr col_seven="00001value" 
                col_eight="00001value" 
                col_nine="00001false"/>
      </currentowner>
      <currentowner col_four="00001bvalue" 
                    col_five="00001bvalue" 
                    col_six="00001bfalse"
                    name = "some_name">
        <addr col_seven="00001bvalue" 
                col_eight="00001bvalue" 
                col_nine="00001bfalse"/>
      </currentowner>
    </owners>
  </dept>
  <dept dept_id="00002" 
            col_two="00002value" 
            col_three="00002value"
            name = "some_name">
    <owners>
      <currentowner col_four="00002value" 
                    col_five="00002value" 
                    col_six="00002false"
                    name = "some_name">
        <addr col_seven="00002value" 
                col_eight="00002value" 
                col_nine="00002false"/>
      </currentowner>
    </owners>
  </dept> 
</depts>
```

Currently I have two loops, one iterates thourgh `child` data, other through `granchild`

```
import pandas
import xml.etree.ElementTree as element_tree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse

tree = element_tree.parse('<HERE_GOES_XML>')
root = tree.getroot()
name_space = {'ns0': 'http://SOMELINK'}

#root
date_from = root.attrib['date']
print(date_from)

#child
for pharma in root.findall('.//ns0:dept', name_space):
    for key, value in pharma.items():
        print(key +': ' + value)
    
#granchild, this must be merged to above so entire script will iterate through entire dept node to move to the next
for owner in root.findall('.//ns0:dept/ns0:owners/ns0:currentowner', name_space):
    owner_dict = {}
    
    for key, value in owner.items():
        print(key +': ' + value)
```

Current result is:

```
2021-01-15
dept_id: 00001
col_two: 00001value
col_three: 00001false
dept_id: 00002
col_two: 00002value
col_three: 00002value
col_four: 00001value
col_five: 00001value
col_six: 00001false
col_four: 00002value
col_five: 00002value
col_six: 00002false
```

I am aiming at nested look that will firstly iterate entire `dept` child with its granchildren and only then move to the next one. Expected result would be below set to be later transformed into `pandas'` dataframe (I will try to work on this next). Some columns have same name between child/granchild thus prefix would be required or looping through only specific `children`.

```
dept.dept_id: 00001
dept.col_two: 00001value
dept.col_three: 00001false
dept.name: some_name
currentowner.col_four: 00001value
currentowner.col_five: 00001value
currentowner.col_six: 00001false
currentowner.name: some_name

currentowner.col_four: 00001bvalue
currentowner.col_five: 00001bvalue
currentowner.col_six: 00001bfalse
currentowner.name: some_name

addr.col_seven: 00001value
addr.col_eight: 00001value
addr.col_nine: 00001false

dept.dept_id: 00002
dept.col_two: 00002value
dept.col_three: 00002value
dept.name: some_name
currentowner.col_four: 00002value
currentowner.col_five: 00002value
currentowner.col_six: 00002false
currentowner.name: some_name
addr.col_seven: 00002value
addr.col_eight: 00002value
addr.col_nine: 00002false
```

[**UPDATE**] - I came across `zip` which should do the trick.

```
dept_list = []
for item in root.iterfind('.//ns0:dept', name_space):
    #print(item.attrib)
    dept_list.append(item.attrib)
#print(dept_list)


owner_list = []
for item in root.iterfind('.//ns0:dept/ns0:owners/ns0:currentowner', name_space):
    #print(item.attrib)
    owner_list.append(item.attrib)
#print(owner_list)

zipped = zip(dept_list, owner_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping can be done in a list comprehension then building dict from navigating the DOM.   Following code goes straight to a data frame.

```
xml = """<depts xmlns="http://SOMELINK" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        date="2021-01-15">
  <dept dept_id="00001" 
            col_two="00001value" 
            col_three="00001false">
    <owners>
      <currentowner col_four="00001value" 
                    col_five="00001value" 
                    col_six="00001false">
        <addr col_seven="00001value" 
                col_eight="00001value" 
                col_nine="00001false"/>
      </currentowner>
    </owners>
  </dept>
  <dept dept_id="00002" 
            col_two="00002value" 
            col_three="00002value">
    <owners>
      <currentowner col_four="00002value" 
                    col_five="00002value" 
                    col_six="00002false">
        <addr col_seven="00002value" 
                col_eight="00002value" 
                col_nine="00002false"/>
      </currentowner>
    </owners>
  </dept> 
</depts>"""

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

root = ET.fromstring(xml)

root.attrib
ns = {'ns0': 'http://SOMELINK'}
pd.DataFrame([{**d.attrib, 
  **d.find("ns0:owners/ns0:currentowner", ns).attrib, 
  **d.find("ns0:owners/ns0:currentowner/ns0:addr", ns).attrib}
 for d in root.findall("ns0:dept", ns)
])
```

### safer version

if any **dept** had no **currentowner** or **currentowner/addr** using `.attrib` would fail.  Walk the DOM considering these elements to be optional.  `dict` keys construction changed to name based on tag of element as well as attribute name.  Structure the way the comprehensions are structured based on your data design.  Need to consider 1 to 1, 1 to optional, 1 to many.  Really goes back to papers that [Codd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgar_F._Codd) wrote in 1970

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
ns = {'ns0': 'http://SOMELINK'}
pd.DataFrame([{**{f"{d.tag.split('}')[1]}.{k}":v for k,v in d.items()}, 
  **{f"{co.tag.split('}')[1]}.{k}":v  for k,v in co.items()}, 
  **{f"{addr.tag.split('}')[1]}.{k}":v for addr in co.findall("ns0:addr", ns) for k,v in addr.items()} }
 for d in root.findall("ns0:dept", ns)
 for co in d.findall("ns0:owners/ns0:currentowner", ns)
])
```

Comment: This looks awsome! I added few updates to expected output as few things came up.

Comment: I forgot that `name` column appears in two nodes thus I would need to add prefix od child or filter in the loop.

Comment: I replaced the source with my original file and got error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrib'`. File has around 20k records.

Comment: Thanks Rob. One thing still occuring. Some nodes have same-name column (updated example). Latest script returns only `name` from `dept` and I need also from `currentowner`. I'm thinking whether root/child name prefix be better.

Comment: Yes! this is it Rob! Regarding prefix at `ns0:dept`. How to add it also at that level?

Comment: follow the pattern of the other two elements...  `**{f"{d.tag.split('}')[1]}.{k}":v for k,v in d.items()}` instead of `**d.attrib`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227463/discussion-between-marcin2x4-and-rob-raymond).

Comment: Rob - I've encountered one more issue. There may be 1+ `currentowner` records in `owners` node. Could you help on tckling that? I updated the sample.

Comment: Updated - see updated comments as well.  Your subsequent use cases are not technical Python / ElementTree / pandas use but really understanding your data design and hence how to navigate it.

Comment: Again, much appreciated! This will be a great for my learning curve ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a depth-first search:

```
root = ElementTree.parse('data.xml').getroot()
ns = {'ns0': 'http://SOMELINK'}

date_from = root.get('date')
print(f'{date_from=}')

for dept in root.findall(f'./ns0:dept', ns):
    for key, value in dept.items():
        print(f'{key}: {value}')
    
    for node in dept.findall('.//*'):
        for key, value in node.items():
            print(f'{key}: {value}')
            
    print()
```

Comment: Could we also add a prefix with `child.` ? I noticed that some columns in my final file have same name on child/granchild level.

Comment: Or we could work on a mechanism that would loop through only specific `child`.

Comment: You can play around with the XPath to get at the nodes you want. `.//*` means looking at all descendants. You don't have to shove everything into the XPath expression either. You can use Python string match to get the ones you want. I don't have access to your actual file so I'm kinda flying blind here. Include a snippet and I can take a look

Comment: I've updated my post with expanded sample. It does now fully represent original file I'm working on. thx!